# Custom User class, password isn't hashed when creating user from the form

Tags: python, django

I've coded my own AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager. Creating users and superusers via terminal works fine. But there is a problem with creating users via form. All user fields are saved properly except password field, which is not hashed (while using set_password()). My models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class MyUserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):
        if not email or not first_name or not last_name or not password:
            raise ValueError('You must provide more data')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('Email address', unique=True, max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=30)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

And my forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import MyUser

class MyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'style': 'margin-top: 0.4em; margin-bottom: 1em'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First name', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'style': 'margin-top: 0.4em; margin-bottom: 1em'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last name', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'style': 'margin-top: 0.4em; margin-bottom: 1em'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'style': 'margin-top: 0.4em; margin-bottom: 1em'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password']
```

I think there is no need to show views.py and html file (full standard).
[image: my form]
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The * is coming from crispy-forms. From the crispy-form docs...

If you don’t like the use of * (asterisk) to denote required fields you have two options:

Asterisks have an asteriskField class set. So you can hide it using CSS rule:

```
.asteriskField {
    display: none;
}
```

Override `field.html` template with a custom one.